# Path tracing cosine hemisphere sampling and emissive objects

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I'm building my own path tracer by self-learning from online resources. But I find that my implementation has an issue with emissive objects in the scene, especially in a dark environment (no skybox).

For example, in the following environment:
[image: image sample]

The box in the middle is the only light source in the environment, with emission value of `(3.0,3.0,3.0)`, and all other objects emission value of `(0.0,0.0,0.0)`. I was expecting the light to scatter smoothly on the walls, but it looks like they are biased towards one direction.

My cosine sampling function is (modified from [lwjgl3-demos](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/main/res/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/raytracing/randomCommon.glsl)):

```
float3 SampleHemisphere3(float3 norm, float alpha = 0.0)
{
    float3 randomVec = rand3();
    float r = saturate(pow(randomVec.x, 1.0 / (1.0 + alpha)));
    float angle = randomVec.y * PI_TWO;
    float sr = saturate(sqrt(1.0 - r * r));
    float3 ph = float3(sr * cos(angle), sr * sin(angle), r);
    float3 tangent = normalize(randomVec * 2.0 - 1.0);
    float3 bitangent = cross(norm, tangent);
    tangent = cross(norm, bitangent);
    return mul(ph, float3x3(tangent, bitangent, norm));
}
```

This is how I compute the shading and next ray info:

```
float3 Shade(inout Ray ray, HitInfo hit)
{
    ray.origin = hit.pos + hit.norm * 1e-5;
    ray.dir = normalize(SampleHemisphere3(hit.norm, 0.0));
    ray.energy *= 2.0 * hit.colors.albedo * saturate(dot(hit.norm, ray.dir));
    return hit.colors.emission;
}
```

And the recursion happens here:

```
// generate ray from camera
Ray ray = CreateCameraRay(camera, PixelCenter);
// trace ray
float3 color = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < _TraceDepth; i++)
{
    // get nearest ray hit
    HitInfo hit = Trace(ray);
    // accumulate color
    color += ray.energy * Shade(ray, hit);
    // if ray has no energy, stop tracing
    if(!any(ray.energy))
        break;
}
// write to frame target
_FrameTarget[id.xy] = float4(color, 1.0);
```

I learned the last two functions from [GPU Path Tracing in Unity](http://three-eyed-games.com/2018/05/12/gpu-path-tracing-in-unity-part-2/).

Here is another example of the similar error:
[image: image sample 2]

I feel that the problem is caused by the cosine weighted hemisphere sampling, but I have no idea how to fix it.

What should I do to get distributed light effect from emissive objects on the diffuse surfaces? Do I have to specify light sources and shapes and sample from them directly instead of emissive objects?

**Edit**:
It is indeed the cosine weighted sampling that is causing the problem.
Instead of:

```
float3 tangent = normalize(randomVec * 2.0 - 1.0);
```

I should have another vector of independent random values:

```
float3 tangent = normalize(rand3() * 2.0 - 1.0);
```

Now it is shows[image: image sample]

Still not perfect, because it is clearly a cross shape. (Probably caused by sparsity of floating values)
How can I further improve this?

**Edit 2**:
After some more debugging and experiments, I figure out the "solution", but I don't understand the reason behind it.

The random value generator is from this [Shadertoy project](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wltcRS), because I see that [GLSL-PathTracer](https://github.com/knightcrawler25/GLSL-PathTracer/blob/master/src/shaders/common/globals.glsl) is also using it.

Here is part of it:

```
void rng_initialize(float2 p, int frame)
{
    //white noise seed
    RandomSeed = uint4(p, frame, p.x + p.y);
}
void pcg4d(inout uint4 v)
{
    v = v * 1664525u + 1013904223u;
    v.x += v.y * v.w;
    v.y += v.z * v.x;
    v.z += v.x * v.y;
    v.w += v.y * v.z;
    v = v ^ (v >> 16u);
    v.x += v.y * v.w;
    v.y += v.z * v.x;
    v.z += v.x * v.y;
    v.w += v.y * v.z;
}
float3 rand3()
{
    pcg4d(RandomSeed);
    return float3(RandomSeed.xyz) / float(0xffffffffu);
}
float4 rand4()
{
    pcg4d(RandomSeed);
    return float4(RandomSeed) / float(0xffffffffu);
}
```

At initialization, I pass `float2(id.xy)` from `SV_DispatchThreadID` and current frame counter to `rng_initialize`.

And here is my new cosine weighted hemisphere sampling function:

```
float3 SampleHemisphere3(float3 norm, float alpha = 0.0)
{
    float4 rand = rand4();
    float r = pow(rand.w, 1.0 / (1.0 + alpha));
    float angle = rand.y * PI_TWO;
    float sr = sqrt(1.0 - r * r);
    float3 ph = float3(sr * cos(angle), sr * sin(angle), r);
    float3 tangent = normalize(rand.zyx + rand3() - 1.0);
    float3 bitangent = cross(norm, tangent);
    tangent = cross(norm, bitangent);
    return mul(ph, float3x3(tangent, bitangent, norm));
}
```

And the results are: (which looks much better)
[image: image sample]

[image: image sample]

[image: image sample]

My discoveries from the experiments are:

1. `r` in the sampling function has to be dependent on `w` component of random values.
2. `angle` can be any in `x`, `y`, `z`.
3. `tangent` has to be dependent on current `xyz` values and a new vector of random `xyz` values. Order doesn't matter so I use `zyx` here. Missing either current `xyz` or new `xyz` will result in a cross shape on the wall.

I'm not sure if this is a correct solution, but as far as my eyes can tell, it solves the problem.

Comment: too lazy to analyze your code but **my guess** is that the problem is PRNG either generator itself or its usage resulting in distribution dependent on screen position biased to diagonals. Other option is you wrongly add up `x` and `y` partial elements of vector (missing sqrt) that usually creates similar patterns. From quick look you are doing a lot of operations on PRN values like: `saturate(pow(randomVec.x, 1.0 / (1.0 + alpha)));` that significantly alters its distribution. Another option is that you use dependent PRN values for stuff that should not be dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I solve it in the new edit.

Comment: nice (such things are hard to debug) so it was related to dependency between PRN values that should not be dependent ... maybe you should create an answer with your findings and remedy

Comment: I think I will leave it as an edit. Hopefully it can help anyone who happens to have the same setup and issue.